# An easy way to create a torch tensor from multiple elements of tuple through concatenate

Tags: python, list, pytorch, tensor

**Inputs**

I have list as follow

```
r1 = [([[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]], 
        [[4, 5, 6], [4, 5, 6]]],
       [[[7, 8], [7, 8]], 
        [[9, 10], [9, 10]]]),

      ([[[11, 12, 13], [11, 12, 13]], 
        [[14, 15, 16], [14, 15, 16]]],
       [[[17, 18], [17, 18]], 
        [[19, 20], [19, 20]]])]
```

I'm going to make 2 torch tensors from the input above.

my desired output is as follow

**output**

```
output = 
[tensor([[[ 1,  2,  3],
          [ 1,  2,  3]],
 
         [[ 4,  5,  6],
          [ 4,  5,  6]],
 
         [[11, 12, 13],
          [11, 12, 13]],
 
         [[14, 15, 16],
          [14, 15, 16]]]), 

 tensor([[[ 7,  8],
          [ 7,  8]],
 
         [[ 9, 10],
          [ 9, 10]],
 
         [[17, 18],
          [17, 18]],
 
         [[19, 20],
          [19, 20]]])]
```

My code is as follows.

```
output = []
for i in range(len(r1[0])):
    templates = []
    for j in range(len(r1)):
        templates.append(torch.tensor(r1[j][i]))
        template = torch.cat(templates)
    output.append(template)
```

Is there a simpler or easier way to get the result I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do:

```
output = [torch.Tensor([*a, *b]) for a, b in zip(*r1)]
```

It concatenates the corresponding items of the two list first then create the Tensor